# How to remove the boundary by given width from 2D mesh?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

I have a flat mesh which consists of a few connected faces (all of which are located at the *lets say* `Z=0.0` plane, I mean the `Z` coordinate of each vertex in the mesh is equal to `0.0`).

I would like to remove the boundary... so to reduce the size of the faces so that area which was closer than a given distance form the external edges gets removed.

It seems something similar to `Extrude region` *along normals*...

How to do so?

PS: @John Here is an illustration of the effect I would expect (Created with Inkscape cause I can see this feature there, it is under `Inkscape > Path > Inset` in Inkscape v1.1.2). The external edges of current surface are red. Yellow lines are the internal edges of the mesh. What I would expect to remain is the blue part of the surface mesh.
**The green part (which is a border of the fixed width all around the plane) I would like to get removed.**
[image]

This is how to get similar effect in Inkscape:
I need this in Blender (3.3.1)

[image]

Comment: It's difficult to work out what you want just from your description. Please add an image, if possible with annotations, indicating what you want. You can save a snapshot of your Blender window via the Window > Save Screenshot menu in Blender.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post.

Comment: you can inset in Blender too. So, why don't you use this function?

Comment: I might be cause I didn't know there is such a function there?

Comment: ...And I have made this following the advice by lemon :)